# Report Builder Spacing DBMemo Delphi

Tags: delphi, border, spacing, reportbuilder

I am using a DBMemo (TPPDBMemo) component in reportbuilder within delphi.  The Stretch property is true but the control doesn't always stretch itself out correctly within the region.

For example if there is lower case text, that dips downward, eg, chars like p,g,q... The bottom part of the text will get cut off if it's on the last line.

I tried adding an event to the onPrint to slightly grow the DBMemo when it prints,

```
    procedure Tfrm.ppDBMemPrint(Sender: TObject); 
    begin
          ppDBMem.Height := ppDBMem.Height + 10;
    end;
```

But this didn't work.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved.  If I could simply add a border to the DBMemo that would be ideal, although I do not see that property anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: fyi you have 3 question asked more than a month ago where you are yet to accept an answer from the ones provided. Please rectify this.